# Como faço para calcular a idade usando php e html?

Tags: php, html

Usando os dados do *html* no *php* como calcular a idade?

Data nascimento no *HTML*:

```
<form method="POST" action="doc.php">
   Nascimento: <input type="date" id="data" name="data">
</form>
```

No *php* eu chamo a data:

```
<?php
     echo $_POST['data']; 
     //a data digitada no formulario html
     //eh exibida no formato yyyy/mm/dd 
?>
```

Agora eu uso a função `date` para saber a data atual, então devo criar a variável `$idade`. Como realizar o cálculo com esses dados?

```
<?php
$dataNasc = $_POST['data'];
$dataAtual = date('Y/m/d');
//portanto, como ficaria a variável idade?
$idade = ?;

    echo "Idade é: $idade Anos";
?>
```

Comment: dei uma olhada, não foi bem isso

Comment: Qual a diferença? A questão aparenta ser exatamente igual, o `date` do input (ao menos no Chrome e Edge) já informam no formato `YYYY-MM-DD`, o que é compatível com as respostas da pergunta que mencionei

Comment: Você quer calcular a idade e a pergunta citada explicitamente faz isso. Não consigo ver como não seria duplicata.

Comment: Resolvido, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
//Resolvi:
<?php
     $data = $_POST['data'];

    // separando yyyy, mm, ddd
    list($ano, $mes, $dia) = explode('-', $data);

    // data atual
    $hoje = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
    // Descobre a unix timestamp da data de nascimento do fulano
    $nascimento = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano);

    // cálculo
    $idade = floor((((($hoje - $nascimento) / 60) / 60) / 24) / 365.25);
     echo "Idade: $idade Anos";
    ?>
```

output:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow. Essa pergunta já existia no site e possuía resposta. Sendo assim, nesses casos sugiro uma pesquisa antes de publicar uma pergunta duplicada, ou ainda uma resposta.